# PayPal: What is difference between callBack url and returnurl?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, paypal

Right now I am working with expression checkout.

I got two properties in API one is **return url** and other one is **callback url.**

I know about return url but when to use callback url?

In case of recurring payments which one is better to use to acknowledge of transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReturnURL is where PayPal will redirect the user after they've completed their review/payment on the PayPal pages.

CallbackURL is used to direct PayPal to a web service that you have setup which can receive the payer's shipping information from PayPal's server, generate shipping and sales tax rates based on that data, and return shipping options back to the PayPal review screen.  This populates the drop-down on this review page with your returned rates so the buyer can choose from those during the PayPal review and eliminate the additional step once they return to your site.

In theory, it's great, but unfortunately, I haven't had good experience with it.  It does work, but it only gives the application a max of 6 seconds to complete everything.  If you're attempting to call out to 3rd party services like UPS, USPS, FedEx, etc. within your callback script in order to obtain rate information, this will generally chew up all that time and PayPal will default to the shipping options you provided with your SetExpressCheckout request.

If you have a real quick method of obtaining shipping rates, though, it's a great system.

Answer (score 0):

> **Return** The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers’ browser after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your site that displays a “Thank you for your payment” page.
>   Default – PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage.
>
> **callback_url** The URL of your Instant Update callback server [useful for keeping track of your inventory, records, etc]

[PayPal Variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

In the case of recurring payments, neither should be used to acknowledge transactions to the user. I believe Paypal send notification emails by default every time they take or give money to an account.

**Note** I'm not a Paypal expert, so please don't hate me if I'm way off. :)